# Trigger a click on Zurb Foundation 4 dropdown

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I would like to dynamically activate the Foundation dropdown when a user adds a product to their basket so that it drops down to show this (without them having to click).

I have tried lots of different ways to click the link dynamically but none have been successful:

jQuery for clicking link:

```
$('#my-basket').trigger('click');
```

Link code:

```
<span id="my-basket" data-dropdown="basket-summary"><i class="icon icon-basket"></i> My Basket <?php if ($shop->basket_count()) echo '(<span>' . $shop->basket_count() . '</span>)'; ?></span>
```

Dropdown code:

```
<div id="basket-summary" class="f-dropdown tiny content" data-dropdown-content>
    <p> Content here</p>
    <a href="/basket">Go to basket</a>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try this `$('span[data-dropdown="basket-summary"]').trigger('click');`

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestions. It doesn't work though :-(
The only thing that works(ish) is to change the display to block with jquery and also edit the absolute positions but this is very hacky and doesn't work cross resolution

Comment: Hmm strange. Can you do `console.log($('#my-basket'))` and see what it returns?

Comment: Oh remove the trigger and paste it before the scrollTop animation .i.e before `$('html, body').animate({` place `$('span[data-dropdown="basket-summary"]').trigger('click');`. Before, the trigger was firing, it's just that the animate function was causing issues.

Comment: Ah, ignore the previous comment. Just noticed your animate is being called twice as you are saying `$('html,body').animate`, change this to just `$('body').animate` and rest will work.

Comment: Got it working great now, although it does seem to want html,body for me? Thanks for your help

Comment: Please add the solution as answer.